# How can I open multiple files the same way explorer.exe does?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-shell

If you select multiple files in Windows Explorer, right click, and open them, some applications (for example, the Windows 10 Photos app) will open only a single instance, with every file available inside the application. Thus far, I have not been able to replicate this in my own application.

My original idea was to manually grab the associated applications, then launch them by passing all the file paths as multiple arguments to a single application call. However, this solution is limited. I can't, for example, invoke UWP apps with this method. I also have tried using `ShellExecute` (and `Process.Start` in C# with the filename as the command), which lets me open a single file in the default application (even if it's UWP), but not multiple file instances.

How can I achieve this effect?